# c# key is not a valid size for this algorithm

Tags: c#, python-3.x, encryption, aes

I am trying to pass this key using python3:

```py
key = base64.b64encode(os.urandom(32))
return key.decode()
```

to this function:

```cs
namespace EncryptionDecryptionUsingSymmetricKey  
{  
    public class AesOperation  
    {  
        public static string EncryptString(string key, string plainText)  
        {  
            byte[] iv = new byte[16];  
            byte[] array;  
  
            using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())  
            {  
                aes.Key = Convert.FromBase64String(key);  
                aes.IV = iv;  
  
                ICryptoTransform encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);  
  
                using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())  
                {  
                    using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream((Stream)memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))  
                    {  
                        using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter((Stream)cryptoStream))  
                        {  
                            streamWriter.Write(plainText);  
                        }  
  
                        array = memoryStream.ToArray();  
                    }  
                }  
            }  
  
            return Convert.ToBase64String(array);  
        }
```

I keep getting this error: "System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Specified key is not a valid size for this algorithm"
The key should work as it is 32 bit?? any ideas??

Comment: `os.urandom(32)` returns 32 **bytes**, not bits.

Comment: @Topaco Here is a test key I printed it from the c# program "3KTR251TxGzjUgjsix3c/gZqaKqaW+bKw1WXjdhIacY="

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to use something like this instead:

```
random_key = os.urandom(16)
```

And don't base encode it, this changes the length.

Comment: I change it to os.urandom(64) and still the same error :( thanks though. I am just trying to implement aes in c# :(

Comment: Oops, had the length adjustment wrong, updated the answer!

Comment: Is it possible to base64 encode it as my server cant handle raw bytes, it is only a flask server??? Thanks ill keep trying tho! Cuz it fetches it from SQL DB if you were wondering